# showing submenu one by one on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually, I am trying to make a sub-menu where user hovers on the first menu its child list should appear one after one and same on the other menu.

I think it is working fine just a minor problem. I am going to the 2nd or 3rd menu before the complete appearing of the first menu's child. 2nd and 3rd are working fine but again if I hover on the first menu it still shows the remaining list (child) which was left to appear.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.animateOneByOne = function(params) {
    params = $.extend({
      css: '',
      duration: 700,
      interval: 300,
      order: 'ASC',
      callback: ''
    }, params);

    if (params.order == 'ASC') {
      elements = $(this);
    } else {
      elements = $(this).get().reverse();
    }

    count = $(this).length - 1;

    $(elements).each(function(id) {
      setTimeout(function(element) {
        if (id == count) {
          $(element).animate(params.css, params.duration, params.callback);
        } else {
          $(element).animate(params.css, params.duration);
        }

      }, id * (params.interval + params.duration), $(this));

    });

  };

})(jQuery);
$('.srvs_dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul li").animateOneByOne({
      css: {
        opacity: '1'
      },
      duration: 450,
      interval: 100

    });
    return false;
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("ul li").css("opacity", 0);

  });
```

```css
.srvs_dropdown li {
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.pi-mm-list {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #09142D;
  width: 250px;
  color: #fff;
}

.pi-mm-list li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  width: 234px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  background-color: #09142D;
  z-index: 999;
}

.pi-mm-list li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pi-mm-list">
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Network Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Firewall and VPN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Application Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Threat Detection &amp; Response</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data Leakage Prevention</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">IPS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Endpoint Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Antivirus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DLP</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Wireless Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Access Point</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Controller</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you create a snippet for this question as it would bring more efficient and quick responses from the members available

Comment: i am still waiting for a solution.... is there any one who can help me

Comment: you just posted the question 5 mins ago and that too without a working example, and you expect from other members to provide you an answer or fix within these 5 mins :)

Comment: Can you please create a working example of your source code, this will give myself and others something to work with to find the existing problem which can then lead to a solution with details of changes and the reason for those changes. Thank you. **Update:** I will edit your question for you.

Comment: I tried to put the code in a snippet but I don't think it looks like how the OP intends it to look. The example above is not enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The source code is all the same but placed into a snippet so it can be executed on the page but I can't seem to see any problem with it other than the text being placed `-30px` top. @SunilSoni make sure you have included the `jQuery` library to since you are using `jQuery`. If you open your browser console you can also view any errors there which would be helpful to include in your question.

Comment: Sir @MuhammadOmerAslam why did you remove that solution.

Comment: it still has flaws and needs to be fixed , will be posting in a few minutes again back

Comment: @SunilSoni i just reposted the answer see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood or observed your question and code, looks like it only works correctly when you hover over all links for the first time top to bottom but once you reach the last menu item in the first block and start hovering in reverse from bottom to top you will see that the submenu links start appearing in randomly, problem is the delay that you have used you just need a small fix i.e `incremental delay` which you were missing. The code below it works as you expect, observe the difference in the `$(elements).each(function(id) {` just replace the `setTimeOut` with delay and add the increment there and watch the difference, you can remove the `interval`  param too see below code and working example, hope it solves the problem.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.animateOneByOne = function(params) {
    params = $.extend({
      css: '',
      duration: 700,
      order: 'ASC',
      callback: ''
    }, params);

    if (params.order == 'ASC') {
      elements = $(this);
    } else {
      elements = $(this).get().reverse();
    }

    count = $(this).length - 1;

    $(elements).each(function(id) {
      let isLastLi = id == count;
      console.log('animate', id);
      (isLastLi) ? $(this).delay((id + 1) * params.duration).animate(params.css, 0, params.callback): $(this).delay((id + 1) * params.duration).animate(params.css, 0);

    });

  };

})(jQuery);


$('.srvs_dropdown').hover(function() {
    console.log('here');
    $(this).find("ul li").animateOneByOne({
      css: {
        opacity: '1'
      },
      duration: 400
    });
    return false;
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("ul li").stop().css("opacity", 0);

  });
```

```css
.srvs_dropdown li {
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.pi-mm-list {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #09142D;
  width: 250px;
  color: #fff;
}

.pi-mm-list li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  width: 234px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  background-color: #09142D;
  z-index: 999;
}

.pi-mm-list li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pi-mm-list">
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Network Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Firewall and VPN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Application Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Threat Detection &amp; Response</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data Leakage Prevention</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">IPS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Endpoint Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Antivirus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DLP</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Wireless Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Access Point</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Controller</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you sir for the solution it's working fine but if i am increasing the duration to 400 it show the same problem. because this time it comes too fast with 200 duration.

Comment: hmm.. let me check it again

Comment: check again now its better,I just updated one more time, and no problem we are all here to help out each other @SunilSoni

Comment: i have not slept for the whole night

Comment: Hi @muhammad, Could you please help me out for one question. [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126251/issue-with-carousel-thumbnail-when-doing-responsive)

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to cancel timed-out function when it doesn't need to execute. It looks that `out` part in `.hover(in, out)` is the best place to do it. But first we need a list of `setTimeout` handlers which are generated in the `in` part. Something like this.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.animateOneByOne = function(params) {
    params = $.extend({
      css: '',
      duration: 700,
      interval: 300,
      order: 'ASC',
      callback: ''
    }, params);

    if (params.order == 'ASC') {
      elements = $(this);
    } else {
      elements = $(this).get().reverse();
    }

    count = $(this).length - 1;
    var handlers = [];
    $(elements).each(function(id) {
      var handle = setTimeout(function(element) {
        if (id == count) {
          $(element).animate(params.css, params.duration, params.callback);
        } else {
          $(element).animate(params.css, params.duration);
        }

      }, id * (params.interval + params.duration), $(this));
      handlers.push(handle);

    });
    return handlers;
  };

})(jQuery);
$('.srvs_dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).data('handler',
      $(this).find("ul li").animateOneByOne({//returns the list of handlers
        css: {
          opacity: '1'
        },
        duration: 450,
        interval: 100
      }));
    return false;
  },
  function() {
    $(this).data('handler').forEach(function(handle) {
      clearTimeout(handle); //cancel setTimeout if it didn't start yet
    });
    $(this).find("ul li").css("opacity", 0);
  });
```

```css
.srvs_dropdown li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.pi-mm-list {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.pi-mm-list li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  width: 234px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  background: #09142D;
  z-index: 999;
}

.pi-mm-list li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pi-mm-list">
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Network Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Firewall and VPN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Application Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Threat Detection &amp; Response</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Data Leakage Prevention</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">IPS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Endpoint Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Antivirus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DLP</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="srvs_dropdown"><a href="#">Wireless Security</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Access Point</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Controller</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```